# How can I add a column to a table using jinja

Tags: python, html, sql, jinja2, cs50

First of all let me tell you that I'm a beginner at this, I'm on the final project of CS50x. My project consists in a webpage that lets you add some weights into a db table, and then it displays those weights and shows you the weight gain/loss. I'm trying to show the results of a query in a table rendered in html using jinja (and python). RP is the identifier(you search for the rp). The desired output is something like this:

[Desired output]

[image: 1]

My python code is the following:

```
@app.route("/weightquery", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def weightquery():

    if request.method == "POST":

        weights = db.execute("SELECT rp, weight, date FROM weights WHERE rp=:rp AND sex=:sex AND user_id=:user_id ORDER BY date DESC",
            rp=request.form.get("rp"), sex=request.form.get("sex"), user_id=session["user_id"])

        gains = db.execute("SELECT weight FROM weights WHERE rp=:rp AND sex=:sex AND user_id=:user_id ORDER BY date DESC",
            rp=request.form.get("rp"), sex=request.form.get("sex"), user_id=session["user_id"])


        animal = request.form.get("rp")
        for i in range(len(gains)):
            for weight in gains[i]:
                if i >= 0 and i < (len(gains)-1):
                    dif= gains[i][weight] - gains[i + 1][weight]
                    # Store the dif somewhere I can access.
                    gains[i].update({'weight': dif})
        # Since the dif will always have one item less, I make sure to delete the last item.            
        gains[i].popitem()
        return render_template("weightqueried.html", weights=weights, gains=gains, animal=animal, dif=dif)

    else:
        return render_template("weightquery.html")
```

My Html template for weightqueried.html is:

```
{% block main %}
   <div class="container">
        <h3>{{ animal }}'s information</h3>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Weight(kg)</th>
                    <th>Weight dif(kg)</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for rp in weights %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ rp['date'] }}</td>
                            <td>{{ rp['weight'] }}</td>
                        </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
     </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Any tips and pointers are greatly appreciated since I'm trying to learn and right now my brain is fried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it can be simplified if `gains` was removed entirely. Iterate over `weights`, do the `dif` calculation, and add the result to each dictionary. Then in the template, add a <td> element for `rp['dif']`. If I understand the problem correctly.....